# Is it safe to send official GREs almost on deadline (e.g., the day before)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre, deadlines

I know I should send emails to the specific institutions rather than ask here. But the problem is it's faster here and I have not much time left, and it's a weekend now.

My GREs and TOEFL are already reported to me. Specifically, I'm asking about Cornell and Yale (physics) departments. They both have a deadline on 15 December. They require the scores by the deadline, but even if I order a score report to them now, ETS needs few business days to send them. So they'll arrive after 15 December, most likely.

Do you think my application will be automatically considered incomplete and dismissed?

Comment: MIT accepts that the scores will be sent by January, albeit its deadline is 15 Dec also

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same predicament. I asked Princeton Admissions about this and they said:

We continue to match scores to applications as we receive them, even after the deadline.  If we already have your scores on file when you submit your application, it can take up to seven business days for the scores to match.  If you recently took an exam or recently made a request to the test administrator to send the scores to Princeton, it can take up to three weeks from the test date for us to receive your official score report and electronically match your scores to your submitted application. You will be able to monitor your submitted application checklist and will see the test date once the scores have matched.  You will not see the test scores.